# How to stub RSpec update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

New to RSpec and having trouble stubbing out an update method (needs to be stubbed) and am running into this error. I have tried a bunch of different ways and can't seem to solve it. I tried to include only the necessary code.

`/spec/controllers/admin/business_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::BusinessesController, type: :controller do
  render_views

  before(:all) do
    @business = build_stubbed(:business)
  end

  describe '#update' do
    before(:each) do
      allow(Business).to receive(:find).and_return(@business)
      @new_name = Faker::Company.name
      @params = { id: @business.id, business: { name: @new_name } }
    end

    it 'updates business name' do
      expect(@business).to receive(:update_attributes).with(name: @new_name, confirm_flag: @business.confirm_flag, phone_primary: @business.phone_primary).and_return(true)
      xhr :patch, :update, id: @business.id, business: { name: @new_name }
      expect(@business.name).to eq(@new_name)
    end
  end
end
```

`/app/controllers/admin/businesses_controller.rb`

```
class Admin::BusinessesController < Admin::BaseAdminController

  def update
    @business.update_attributes(business_params)
  end

  def business_params
    params.require(:business).permit(:name, :active_flag).merge(confirm_flag: true, phone_primary: '')
  end

end
```

When I run this test I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Admin::BusinessesController#update updates business name
 Failure/Error: @business.update_attributes(business_params)

   #<Business:0x007fc43c4f5738> received :update_attributes with unexpected arguments
     expected: ({:name=>"Fadel, Larson and Hettinger", :confirm_flag=>true, :phone_primary=>"7832900175"})
          got: ({"name"=>"Fadel, Larson and Hettinger", "confirm_flag"=>true, "phone_primary"=>""})
   Diff:
   @@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
   -[{:name=>"Fadel, Larson and Hettinger",
   -  :confirm_flag=>true,
   -  :phone_primary=>"7832900175"}]
   +[{"name"=>"Fadel, Larson and Hettinger",
   +  "confirm_flag"=>true,
   +  "phone_primary"=>""}]
```

So it looks like the `phone_primary` is causing the problem and I change my test expectation line to be:

```
  describe '#update' do
    before(:each) do
      allow(Business).to receive(:find).and_return(@business)
      @new_name = Faker::Company.name
      @params = { id: @business.id, business: { name: @new_name } }
    end

    it 'updates business name' do
      expect(@business).to receive(:update_attributes).with(name: @new_name, confirm_flag: @business.confirm_flag, **phone_primary: ''**).and_return(true)
      xhr :patch, :update, id: @business.id, business: { name: @new_name }
      expect(@business.name).to eq(@new_name)
    end
  end
```

and i get the failure:

```
Failures:

  1) Admin::BusinessesController#update updates business name
 Failure/Error: expect(@business.name).to eq(@new_name)

   expected: "Flatley Inc"
        got: "Samara Kuhic"
```

And now the names aren't matching

Comment: Add `.and_call_original` to your stubbing of `update_attributes`. Right it doesn't do any updating and your later expectation fails, naturally.

Comment: im stubbing..not hitting the database on purpose

Comment: You see, when you stub a method (_on purpose_!), you can't also expect it to do its job. Because you stubbed it. Having a cake and eating it too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so there's no way to stub an update method in RSpec?

Comment: There is a way, you're doing it. As I'm saying, you can't have a cake __and__ eat it. You have to choose, which one you want.

Comment: Just in case you don't understand my analogies: "not hitting the database on purpose" - you're also not doing _any_ updates. Including update to business name, which you later expect to happen.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for your help. Just gonna test the response then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125003/discussion-between-alisontague-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 2):

I ended up stubbing the reload by using assigns. My tests are now passing with this:

```
 describe '#update' do
   before(:each) do
     allow(Business).to receive(:find).and_return(@business)
     @new_name = Faker::Company.name
   end

   it 'updates business name' do
      expect(@business).to receive(:update_attributes).with(name: @new_name, confirm_flag: true, phone_primary: '').and_return(@business)
      xhr :patch, :update, id: @business.id, business: { name: @new_name }
      expect(assigns(:business)).to eq(@business)
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
```

Not sure if this is the preferred way but it's passing for me. Looks like `assigns` will be deprecated in Rails 5

Comment: Me personally, I never bother with controller tests. Maybe only for some tricky routing logic. Business logic checks either go to feature specs (where there's no stubbing) or unit specs (unlimited stubbing).

Comment: Controller specs are in this weird middle ground where you _have_ to do some stubbing (for auth, etc.), but you don't want to do too much of it (or else your test becomes disconnected from reality).

Answer (score 0):

If you check your original code, in your controller you have this:

```
def business_params
  params.require(:business).permit(:name, :active_flag).merge(confirm_flag: true, phone_primary: '')
end
```

you're always setting `confirm_flag` to `true` and `phone_primary` to `''`(empty string). And in your test you have this:

```
expect(@business).to receive(:update_attributes).with(name: @new_name, confirm_flag: @business.confirm_flag, phone_primary: @business.phone_primary).and_return(true)
```

so, if you check `confirm_flag` you're setting it to `@business.confirm_flag` which in this case in fact is `true` and it's fine with what you're setting in the controller, but the problem comes with `phone_primary` which is being set to `@business.phone_primary`, and in this case `@business.phone_primary` is `7832900175`, and that's why it is failing.

So, to fix this, you either have to change your test to:

```
expect(@business).to receive(:update_attributes).with(name: @new_name, confirm_flag: @business.confirm_flag, phone_primary: '').and_return(true)
```

or change your controller code to `permit` `phone_primary` from the params, which will also fix your error.

Comment: If you read the rest of my question you'll see that I changed the primary phone and it didn't fix the problem as the name does'nt update in the test

Comment: what are those ** you put around `phone_primary ` ?

Comment: someone already gave you a comment about your other error, looks like you thought that error was for the same test.

Comment: the stars were meant to bold the change..sorry it looks that way. The errors are from the same spec but were edited to make the question more readable..ive updated

Comment: I see, so, it looks like your record was updated with the new name, which is fine, isn't it ?, and your expect line is this: `expect(@business.name).to eq(@new_name)`, which is comparing `@business.name`(which has the previous name) against `@new_name` which is the new name. So, before comparing those values, just reload the object from the database again with `@business.reload`, that way `@business` will be reloaded with the new name.

Comment: @fanta: I think it's not updated. He _stubs_ the `update_attributes`. How can it be updated? Also, reloading would not be needed here (due to how stubbing is set up)

Comment: @fanta How do I reload the object in a stubbing way?